# what can be the reasons for a fork call not entering child code

Tags: linux, fork, parent-child, telnet

I have this piece of code in a program function.
And there is a test script which hits this code path.
script goes through this function multiple times (~1000).

fork() call is successful as I can see child pid from parent block syslog but I don't see anything from child block.

This does NOT happen always. Happens only once in a hundred attempts.

Any idea what can be the general reasons for this to happen.

And what should I look for to get more information about the failure.

```
int i;

if ((i = fork()) < 0) {
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "(%s): fork failed!\n", __func__);
}
if (i) {
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "(%s): fork Parent: id: %d\n", __func__, i);
} else {
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "(%s): fork child\n", __func__);
    /* Do something */
}

Output:
telnetd[24600]: (startslave): fork Parent: id: 24601
<Thats it, no log after this!!>
```

To be exact, this is a part of freeBSD telnetd startslave() code, and script is just trying to login using telnet and logout for 1000 times and it fails sometimes. Failure is guaranteed, it can happen may be after 100 attempts or may be after 700 attempts.

Comment: The child process doesn't have the same terminal as the parent.

Comment: can you please explain it in some more details, as I said this failure is seen only once in say 200 attempts. It does not happen always.

Comment: Well, I just checked and actually I was wrong. For me, your code wrapped in an `int main()` and using `printf()` instead of the logger function you use outputs both strings.

Comment: ok, so any idea, in general when can this happen?

Comment: All I can think of is that the created child process is nt scheduled for execution may be because of some other high priority process at that time. so scheduler might not picked up the child proc and scheduled it. BUT all this is done in kernel. 
If at all this is the situation behind this, HOW can I confirm this?

Is there any way to increment this child proc priority (nice system call or something) and can confirm that it gets executed if it has priority!?

Any thoughts!

Comment: it's strange, as I stated, for me this works.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS,0,20);
And thus by increasing priority of the process (before forking) child is always getting a chance to run, and script went through fine 1000 out of 1000 times. Thanks

Comment: are you compiling with --enable-pthreads, or -lpthreads or similar?